# Reversing a css animation

Tags: css, css-animations, reverse

I have an overlay which fades in with the following code,

```
.overlay {
    background: rgba(32, 79, 156, 0.97);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
   display: none;


}

.overlay.active {
    display: block;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
     animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}





@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        display:none; 
        opacity: 0;
    }

    1% {
        display: block ; 
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        display: block ; 
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

all my js does is toggle the class

```
$('.hamburger').on('click', function(){
       $('.overlay, .hamburger').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

How can I reverse this animation? at the moment it just jumps back to the previous state.

Answer (score 1):

Animations won't work on the `display` property as `display:none` hides the element so you wouldn't see it fade even if the animation was running. You can simply animate the `opacity` property using [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) like this:

```js
$('.hamburger').on('click', function(){
       $('.overlay, .hamburger').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

```css
.overlay {
    background: rgba(32, 79, 156, 0.97);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity:0;
    pointer-events:none;
    -webkit-transition: scale, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: scale, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: scale, opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: scale, opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.overlay.active {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamburger">hamburger</div>
<div class="overlay">overlay</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your toogle button go hide because the overlay overlaps the button, try put the button with a higher z-index above overlay. With the animation you can use `opacity` and `transition`

**CSS**

```
.hamburger{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1001;
}

.hamburger.active{
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.overlay {
    background: rgba(32, 79, 156, 0.97);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;    
}

.overlay.active {
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    opacity:1;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/yprb0bjp/4/)**

Comment: I think the OP's issue is with the animation itself. Specifically, that when hiding the `.overlay` there *is none*.

Comment: Ah! oK i will change it